# Trying to check everything adjacent in Matrix

Tags: java, matrix, project

I was wondering if there was a more simple way to do this? The project requires me to write this method that uses another method that returns a Boolean of true or false if there is treasure located there. I got that method down, but it now wants me to write a method that returns how much treasure is located adjacent (in all directions) to a set place in a row and column. I mapped this out on a piece of paper and came out with... this. But, I feel like I am repeating code but I don't understand any other way that can satisfy the condition. I would love for it to be more condensed... I was thinking 2 for loops? But there's two conditions that wouldn't work in the for loop.

```
    //precondition: 0<=row<rows in map and 0<=col<cols in map
//postcondition: returns a count of the number of treasures in the cells adjacent to the location row,col 
//horizontally, vertically, and diagonally.  
public int numAdjacent(int row, int col) {
    if(hasTreasure(row,col)) {
        return -1;
    }

    int numOfTreasure = 0;
    if ((0<=row && row < mapHeight()) && (0<=col && col < mapWidth())) {
        if(hasTreasure(row - 1,col - 1)) {
            numOfTreasure++;
        }
    }
    if (0<=row && row < mapHeight()) {
        if(hasTreasure(row - 1,col)) {
            numOfTreasure++;
        }
    }
    if ((0<=row && row < mapHeight()) && 0<=col && col < mapWidth()) {
        if(hasTreasure(row - 1,col + 1)) {
            numOfTreasure++;
        }
    }
    if (0<=row && row < mapHeight()) {
        if(hasTreasure(row + 1,col)) {
            numOfTreasure++;
        }
    }
    if ((0<=row && row < mapHeight()) && 0<=col && col < mapWidth()) {
        if(hasTreasure(row + 1,col + 1)) {
            numOfTreasure++;
        }
    }
    if ((0<=row && row < mapHeight()) && 0<=col && col < mapWidth()) {
        if(hasTreasure(row + 1,col - 1)) {
            numOfTreasure++;
        }
    }
    if (0<=col && col < mapWidth()) {
        if(hasTreasure(row,col + 1)) {
            numOfTreasure++;
        }
    }
    if (0<=col && col < mapWidth()) {
        if(hasTreasure(row,col - 1)) {
            numOfTreasure++;
        }
    }
    return numOfTreasure;
}
```

Comment: Why are you immediately returning `-1` if there is treasure located at the current coordinate?  If that's important, I'll modify my answer to reflect that.

Comment: It is, because hasTreasure is this:

    `public boolean hasTreasure(int row, int col) {
        if(row>map.length || col> map[0].length || row < 0 && col < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("out of bounds on map");
        }
        return map[row][col];
    } `

But that for some reason is throwing me an error too.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you return `-1` though if it **has** treasure located at that coordinate.

Comment: I thought that was a way to skip it, i'm somewhat new to code like this.. Would it just not add anything to treasure and skip?

Comment: If treasure was located at that coordinate, your method would return `-1` without checking any of its adjacent neighbors, which is definitely not the correct outcome.  You have the right idea when you check the bounds before the if-statements, but you're not using the correct values.

Comment: So basically i'm just going to check for 1 and 0 (true/false) and if it's one or another add to numOfTreasure?

Comment: Yes, you iterate over each adjacent neighbor (which is in bounds) and increment `numOfTreasure` by `1` if treasure is located at that neighbor.  See my answer below for an example implementation.

Comment: Thank you!! Now it works perfectly, I was freaking out for so long.

Comment: This question been asked before. Just check the questions of minesweeper.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with using nested for-loops!  Because we're dealing with a matrix, each element has 8 adjacent neighbors at which treasure can be located.  For this reason, we can use nested for-loops to check if each adjacent neighbor has treasure; if the neighbor's coordinates are out-of-bounds, we simply skip it within the loop.

```
public int numAdjacent(int row, int col) {
    int numOfTreasure = 0;

    for (int currentCol = col - 1; currentCol <= col + 1; currentCol++) {
        for (int currentRow = row - 1; currentRow <= row + 1; currentRow++) {
            if (currentRow < 0 || currentRow >= mapHeight() || currentCol < 0 || currentCol >= mapWidth()) {
                continue;
            }

            numOfTreasure += hasTreasure(currentRow, currentCol) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    return numOfTreasure;
}
```

Once you understand that for-loop, it can be simplified even further:

```
public int numAdjacent(int row, int col) {
    int numOfTreasure = 0;

    for (int currentCol = Math.max(0, col - 1); currentCol <= Math.min(col + 1, mapWidth() - 1); currentCol++) {
        for (int currentRow = Math.max(0, row - 1); currentRow <= Math.min(row + 1, mapHeight() - 1); currentRow++) {
            numOfTreasure += hasTreasure(currentRow, currentCol) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    return numOfTreasure;
}
```